# Fix nodes overlap in Cytoscape (RCy3)

Tags: r, cytoscape

I need to plot network with labels on nodes. Node names lengths are sometimes short, sometimes long. Data is dynamically generated so it's a kind of random every time.

Here is my example with data:

```
links=data.frame(
    source=c("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","J", "BBBBBBBBB",
             "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCCCCCC", "CCCCCCCCCCC", "D","IIIIIIII"),
    target=c("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB","BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCCCCCC", "D", 
             "J","AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","E", "F", "G", "H", "IIIIIIII","IIIIIIII")
)


library(RCy3)

nodes <- data.frame (id = unique(c(links$source,links$target)) )

createNetworkFromDataFrames(nodes, links, title="my first network", collection="DataFrame Example")

setNodeShapeDefault('RECTANGLE', style.name = "default")
setEdgeTargetArrowShapeDefault("ARROW", style.name = "default")
setNodeBorderColorDefault("#000000", style.name = "default")
setNodeColorDefault("#89D0F5", style.name = "default")
setNodeWidthDefault(130, style.name = "default")

exportImage("c:\\temp\\network_01.svg", 'svg')
```

Here is my result picture:

[image]

Labels do not fit rectangles, nodes overlap. Upper link is out of plot edge. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are really asking two questions:

1. How to avoid labels not fitting into the node:  There are two approaches to this.  First, since you know the length of the labels, you can easily change the width of the nodes.  Second, you can wrap the labels using the NODE_LABEL_WIDTH property and set that to the width of the nodes.
2. How to make sure the upper link is in the plot:  You need to do a fit content in order to resize the plot after you are done adding all of your nodes.  You can do this by using the RCy3 fitContent() method or by redoing the layout.